# Parsing a binary MOBI file: best approach?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, parsing

It contains METADATA in between binary data. I'm able to parse the first line with the title Agent_of_Chang2e, but I need to get the metadata on the bottom of the header as well. I know there are not standard specifics for it.

[image]

This code isn't able to decode the bottom lines. For example I get the following wrong formatted text:

> ```
> FÃHANGE</b1èrX)¯­ÌiadenÕniverse<sup><smalÀ|Â®¿8</¡Îovelÿ·?=SharonÌeeándÓteveÍiller8PblockquoteßßÚ>TIa÷orkyfiction.Áll@eãacÐ0hðortrayedén{n)áreïrzus0¢°usly.Ôhatíean0authhmxétlõp.7N_\
> ```
>
> ©ßÂ© 1988âyÓOOKãsòeserved.0ðart)publicaZmayâehproduc

```
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    char buffer[1024];
    FILE* file = fopen([path UTF8String], "r");
    if (file != 0)
    {
        while(fgets(buffer, 1024, file) != NULL)
        {
            NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString: buffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@",string);
            [string release];
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    [pool drain];
```

Comment: are you sure it's ASCII and not UTF8 or some other latin/roman format? (I see `NSASCIIStringEncoding`)

Comment: I assume you have see this? http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/MOBI#PalmDOC_Header seems relevant.

Comment: You might find HexFiend useful for this kind of work: http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/

Comment: @nielsbot Just to make it short: I have tried all available encodings.

Comment: @nielsbot Yes, I've it under my nose, but it doesn't matter how I scan the text file, I always get the above mentioned content and I'm not able to extract the metadata specified in the documentation.

Comment: @nielsbot Do you mean i need to use this framework? I can't do it with native apple APIs?

Comment: How about making a file available for us to try and read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nielsbot already posted a [link to the format specification](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/MOBI#PalmDOC_Header).

As you can read there, the file is not text file, but binary encoded. Parsing it with `NSString` instances is no good idea.

You have to read the file binary, i. e. using `NSData`:

```
NSData content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Then you have to take out the relevant information by yourself. For example, if you want to read the uncompressed text length, you will find in the linked document that this information starts at position 4 and has a length of 4.

```
int32_t uncompressedTextLength; // 4 bytes are 32 bit.
[content getBytes:&uncompressedLenght range:NSMakeRange(4, 4)];
```

Maybe you have to deal with endianess.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSTask` or `system()` to pass the file through the `strings` utility and parse the output of that:

```
strings /bin/bash | more
...
...
677778899999999999999999999999999999:::;;<<====>>>>>>>>>>>????????   
@(#)PROGRAM:bash  PROJECT:bash-92
...
...
```

Comment: Did you try this? How did you get on?

Answer (score 0):

First, I am pretty sure the texts will be UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoded.

Second, you cannot just take random 1024 bytes and expect them to work as a text. What about byte order (big endian vs little endian)?

Comment: UTF-8 does not have a byte order issue, it is a completely defined order on all platforms and in transit. Where problems arise is that not all data is a valid UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 encoding, in fact there is a small chance that random data will be a valid unicode string. There are a few encodings that can accommodate al 256 byte values but they include non-printable characters so are not generally useful.

Comment: @zapth UTF-8 doesn't have a byte order issue but UTF-16 does. On the other hand, there are byte character sequences in UTF-16 that are not valid for UTF-8 to parse.

Comment: UTF-16 and UTF-8 are different encodings and any codepoint can be expressed in either. Ignoring surrogste pairs and etc. UTF-16 representation of code points are either 2 or 4 bytes in length, UTF-8 representation of code points are 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes in length.

Comment: @zaph I know how the encoding works. That's why I am saying that one encoding cannot be blindly parsed as a different encoding because the parsing can crash or result in an unreadable text.

Comment: Not so sure, you have posted that UTF-8 is 1, 2 or 3 bytes, that is incorrect. Using `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` on `NSString`s that include emoji will encode the emoji as UTF-16 encodings: "" produces hex 5c756438 33645c75 64633766 which is ASCII: "\ud83d\udc7f"

Comment: @zaph There are different versions of UTF-8. There is one which is widely used and doesn't allow more than 3 bytes for a character (~ the same charset encoded by UTF-16). Note that the original UTF-8 spec allows up to 6 bytes (covering all UTF-32 characters).

Comment: The original version of UTF-8 allowed 6 bytes, that was reduced to 4 bytes when codepoints were reduced to 21 bits. See [UTF-8 description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description): "The original specification covered numbers up to 31 bits (the original limit of the Universal Character Set). In November 2003, UTF-8 was restricted by [RFC 3629](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629) to end at U+10FFFF, in order to match the constraints of the UTF-16 character encoding. This removed all 5- and 6-byte sequences, and 983040 4-byte sequences."

Comment: You may be confusing CESU-8 with UTF-8, some databases uses this initially as a UTF-8 like encoding. Each CESU-8 character code (1, 2, or 3 bytes) can be converted to exactly one UTF-16 code unit (2 bytes) CESU-8 is not an official part of the Unicode Standard